# Matrix malloc Image Processing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-management, uiimage

I 'm trying to develop an Image Processing application for the images stored
at the photo library of the iPhone, but to tell the truth I am confused.
I'm interested in getting the A R G B matrixes out of the image. then make
some algorithm with these matrixes and then releasing them.
What would you prefer for the aforementioned method? Developing the algorithm
with 2-dimensional matrixes using "malloc" and then "free" or would you use 1-dimensional matrixes with both "malloc" and "free"? When I 'm not using malloc I face problems with the memory, probably it's not enough to store both the uiimage and all these matrixes at the same time at the memory.
P.S I'm working on 3MP images.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use malloc and access the matrix through accessor functions which compute the 1-D index from the 2-D coordinates.